# IE/IIS troubleshooting help needed

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer, iis, tls1.2

I have a very odd scenario. I have two websites, a live website and a test website, both are public sites. The "live" site works fine with all browsers & OSes. The test website which was originally what the live website was cloned from, works with Chrome, and IE 11 (On Windows 10) and Edge. It does not however, work with IE 11 on Windows 7.

I have looked through both of the IIS servers for differences including TLS differences, and could not find any.

The error is "This page can’t be displayed" In some cases I get the following;

"Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings"

I tried changing all combinations of TLS & SSL settings on the browser with no positive effect. I tried 4 different Windows 7 machines running IE 11 and they all fail with "This page can’t be displayed" some get the "Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings" and others don't.

I checked the IIS log on the test server and it does not log any access from Win7/IE browsers. It does log the access from chrome and Win10/IE browsers.

I tried Fiddler, and it reports an internal type error when trying to access the test website. The error was "HTTPS handshake to  failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

I checked the event viewer on the client & server, no relevant errors reported.

What I am hoping for is help in trying to get some pointers on how to further troubleshoot the issue.

EDIT:

Based on comments below I ran Qualsys. The results from the two servers show a difference which explains the problem. I do not know how to effect the change which will make the test server work however.  Here is part of the results from;

Live Server;

```
Cipher Suites 
# TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order) 


TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  128 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK  256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK  128 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK  256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK  128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)   WEAK  256 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)   WEAK  128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)   WEAK  256 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)   WEAK  128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)   WEAK  256 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)   WEAK  128 




Handshake Simulation 

IE 11 / Win 7  R     RSA 2048 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384   ECDH secp256r1   FS    
IE 11 / Win 8.1  R   RSA 2048 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2 > http/1.1      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384   ECDH secp256r1   FS    
IE 11 / Win Phone 8.1  R     RSA 2048 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2 > http/1.1      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256   ECDH secp256r1   FS    
IE 11 / Win Phone 8.1 Update  R  RSA 2048 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2 > http/1.1      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384   ECDH secp256r1   FS
```

Test Server;

```
Cipher Suites
# TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   128


Handshake Simulation
IE 11 / Win 7  R    Server closed connection
IE 11 / Win 8.1  R  Server closed connection
IE 11 / Win Phone 8.1  R    Server closed connection
IE 11 / Win Phone 8.1 Update  R Server closed connection
```

Comment: I checked one of the clients I am testing with and KB3140245 was installed in 2016.

Comment: I ran the qualsys scanner, and there are differences that explain the problem, but using NARTAC I can't see the differences, nor how to change the items in question. I will post an EDIT to my original question with more information.

Comment: Then clearly IE 11 no longer has ciphers to use when connecting to your test server (hardened for TLS 1.2), which is a good thing. You should know that most popular sites today no longer support IE 11.

Comment: Yes that is all well and good, but how can I "unharden" the test server to match the Live server? Having a test server which does not match the live server makes testing useless as you don't know what is causing any given issue.

Comment: It looks to me like using "best" template with [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) could make it work. There's a `/backup filename` option from the command line to run first if it isn't available from the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction I needed was defined in the comments. What I did was to reset the IIS Crypto "Best Practices" and reboot. Once complete using IIS Crypto I removed the TLS 1.0 & TLS 1.1. After a reboot, things worked.

Comment: I request you to mark the solution as an answer, it will help other people who face a similar issue.